# What is a good prayer to get away from abusers?

Tags: dua, helping

May peace be upon you brothers and sisters!

I am a PhD student and I am going through really hard times. The person whom I am working with is abusing me. She is always giving me duties that she knows that I can't fulfill on time. She asks me to help others but when  I ask for help she yells at me saying that I have no authority to ask for help. The only reason why I am staying in this abusive environment is because my career depends on this. But Allah knows my heart, I can't take this anymore. I don't want to curse this person but I want my rights. I tried to talk to her she constantly yells at me or blames me or makes me feel stupid. I am doing nothing other than working hard (literally spending 20 hours a day). This is not sustainable. Please keep me in your prayers and share any prayers that you know that I can recite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help from people who have higher positions than her to stop her and do the required actions about this matter. You can also file a lawsuit against her if that was ever needed.

It is very recommended **in Islam** to have the patience for the pain that people cause. There are many verses regarding this, but, again, this doesn't mean you can't take any other way in order to stop what you are going through if you are having such a hard time that you can't bear.

Some of the verses concerning patience:

In [Surah Ash-Shuraa (42) - Verse 43](https://quran.com/42/43):

{

In Arabic (the original text):

> وَلَمَنْ صَبَرَ وَغَفَرَ إِنَّ ذَلِكَ لَمِنْ عَزْمِ الْأُمُورِ

Its translation:

> And whoever is patient and forgives - indeed, that is of the matters [requiring] determination.

- The verse means that you will be rewarded for your patience. covering on what you are going through, and forgiveness as those are the deeds that Allah Almighty order us to do.

}

In [Surah Al-Nahl (16) - Verse 126](https://quran.com/16/126):

{

In Arabic (the original text):

> وَإِنْ عَاقَبْتُمْ فَعَاقِبُوا بِمِثْلِ مَا عُوقِبْتُمْ بِهِ ۖ وَلَئِنْ صَبَرْتُمْ لَهُوَ خَيْرٌ لِلصَّابِرِينَ

Its translation:

> And if you punish [an enemy, O believers], punish with an equivalent of that with which you were harmed. But if you are patient - it is better for those who are patient.

- The verse states that if you want to get back to them, then take refuge in Qisas equivalently (be aware that it shouldn't cause more harm to them than what they caused to you), but if you tolerate whatever you are going through, then it is best for you because of what awaits you in the afterward of rewards, and you will get over your enemies in the worldly life.

}

In [Surah Al-Muzzammil (73) - Verse 10](https://quran.com/73/10):

{

In Arabic (the original text):

> وَاصْبِرْ عَلَى مَا يَقُولُونَ وَاهْجُرْهُمْ هَجْراً جَمِيلاً

Its translation:

> And be patient over what they say and avoid them with gracious avoidance.

- The verse encourages to have patience toward those who talk to/about you badly and leave them without inclining to have revenge.

}

And [a Hadith about patience](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13835/it-is-mustahabb-to-isolate-oneself-at-times-of-tribulation-when-the-muslim-fears-he-may-lose-his-religious-commitment):

{

The Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him) said:

> "The believer who mixes with people and patiently bears their annoyance will have a greater reward than the believer who does not mix with people and patiently bear their annoyance."
>
> Narrated by *Al-Tirmidhi (5207) and Ibn Maajah (4032)*
>
> Classed as *Saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi, 2035*

}

There are many Du'as to recite for getting over hard times and being patient. You can make your own Du'a from your own words, but nevertheless, here's [a Du'a](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi77_zCoeviAhWMKFAKHcBQD7cQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F366199013425607716%2F&psig=AOvVaw0MWiu2B9vM4-h-fMAoOz1N&ust=1560680350135473):

> O Allah, grant me ease, the courage, and strength to keep on going and the patience to trust in your plans.

---

[Source](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/36349/)